# Mongodb inserts one more document if I edit particular field such as flag like "email sent" ? corresponding JAVA POJO class has issue?

Tags: java, mongodb

Mongodb inserts one more document if I edit particular field such as flag like "email sent" ? what can be the issue  ? corresponding JAVA POJO class has issue?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, POJO was not having @Id marked ID as one of the item in JAVA class. After Adding ID property with @Id annotation, same document was getting modified instead of adding new document in collection.